# add y=0 line in some plots facet_grid ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

I have a big plot, using `facet_grid()`.
I want to add a vertical line to indicate y=0, but only in some of the plot.

Reproducible example -

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100,sd=0.5), type = rep(c('A','B'), 50))
ggplot(df) + facet_grid(type~.) +
     geom_point(data = df[df$type == 'A',], mapping = aes(x=x, y=y)) +
     geom_rect(data = df[df$type == 'B',], mapping=aes(xmin=x,ymin=0,xmax=(x+2),ymax=y)) +
     theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"))
```

I want the line only in the top ptot for example.

Comment: or `+ geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = c('black', 'transparent'))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create another data object for an hline geom and make sure to include the relevant faceted variable.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100,sd=0.5), type = rep(c('A','B'), 50))
ggplot(df) + facet_grid(type~.) +
     geom_point(data = df[df$type == 'A',], mapping = aes(x=x, y=y)) +
     geom_rect(data = df[df$type == 'B',], mapping=aes(xmin=x,ymin=0,xmax=(x+2),ymax=y)) +
     geom_hline(data = data.frame(type="A", y=0), mapping=aes(yintercept=y)) +
     theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! great solution. 
In my case it's a little bit more complex, because I don't know what will be the facet variable name, but I can find out from the input.
Much appreciated!